# Acess the value of a key in the html component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i'll keep it simple.I have the following map:

```
export class Component {

    total: Map<string, number> = new Map([["test1", 2],["test2",3]])
}
```

How can I access a particular value using its key in the html component?.I tried the following code without success and all examples that i found use an ngFor which i don't want to use.

**test.component.html**

```
{{total[test1]}}
{{total.get(test1)}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "without success" mean exactly? do you get an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget the quotes for the `string` type key.

```
{{total.get('test1')}}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an array of arrays, therefore an additionl index access is required

```
{{total[0]['test1']}}
{{total[1]['test2']}}
```

or

```
{{total[0].test1}}
{{total[1].test2}}
```